# MySQL: How to migrate data and save relationships

Tags: mysql, sql

At my local MySQL instance I have a schema with three tables and each one of them is in relations with other (relations is one-to-one and one-to many between them).
On production MySQL instance I have exactly the same schema and tables. I need to migrate all the data with all existing relationships. At the time of migration there is possibility that production instance will contain some data, so creating dump of my schema from localhost and installing it on prod is not an option (as it will likely drop existing schema and after that insert data rows).

I am searching for the next solution: migrate the data (just append it to existing tables saving all relationships in new data and keep existing at the time of migration data, not drop tables) through file from identical tables from one instance of MySQL to another.

Are there any solutions to this ?

Comment: Consider adding a column that indicates (for instance) where the data comes from. This column will become part of a compound primary key, ensuring that there can be no duplicates/clashes.

Comment: @Strawberry too complicated for the case. This will be done only once (we are migrating from NoSQL db to MySQL).

Comment: You can create dump and import data to another database on production env. Than you can merge data using SQL like `insert select * from where not exists` or something like this. Is it the option?

Comment: @ravnur it is an option but I hoped there is like 'soft' variant of dump, where data just appends.

Comment: also you can try `--replace` option for mysqldump. It will generate replace statements instead of insert but it should be tested carefully and will work if not only tables have PK|UK.